# Python & SQLite SELECT BETWEEN Date Range Issue

Tags: python, sqlite, date, filtering, qsqlquery

I have created a Dynamic GUI using PyQt and SQLite. Users currently have the ability to filter data using different criteria; however, I am having an issue with filtering between a date range. Currently, the following line of code works, but only if the users selects a date range within the same month. For example,

1. [SELECT * FROM tblx WHERE EventDate BETWEEN '9/1/2016' and '9/30/2016'] yields 8 results of 300 [perfect!].

However, when I arbitrarily select two dates outside of a given month, ex:

2. [SELECT * FROM tblx WHERE EventDate BETWEEN '10/13/2016' and '12/30/2016'] it returns *null*.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Thanks for the help!

```
def FilterBetweenDates(self):
            start = self.startDate.text()
            finish = self.endDate.text()
            filter = "EventDate BETWEEN '{}' AND '{}'".format(start, finish)
            print(filter) 
            self.model.setFilter(filter)
```

Also: I have already attempted switch the date input date format to: YYYY-MM-DD. And, I have use the following statement:

```
#filter = "EventDate BETWEEN strftime('%Y %m %d','{}') AND strftime('%Y %m %d','{}')".format(start, finish)
```

Result remains unchanged.

Comment: Maybe there are no data in that range? Have you tried `9/1/2016` and `12/30/2016`? (BTW your code is prone to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Technical_implementations).)

Comment: Dates in SQLite are formatted in the ISO8601 format, e.g. YYYY-MM-DD, see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html and the duplicate.

Comment: @kennytm. The result should be 23. Also, I still get the same effect if I write it as a parameterized query.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. I already attempted the following: filter = "EventDate BETWEEN strftime('%Y %m %d','{}') AND strftime('%Y %m %d','{}')".format(start, finish)..... Same Result!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: This is not a duplicate question. I know ISO8601 procedure.